# как сделать одинаковый фиксированный отступ всем span, без margin конкретно каждому из них

Tags: html, css, css3, scss, grid

```html
<div class="contact">
  <ul>
    <p> CONTACT US :</p>
    <li>Mywebsite.Com Socaial <span> Media Username</span>
    <li>Username@domain.com <span>Socaial Media name</span>
    <li>Phone : 0895 788 <span>Socaial Media Username</span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Современный вариант:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 0 1em;
}

li {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <p> CONTACT US :</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Mywebsite.Com Socaial <span> Media Username</span>
    <li>Username@domain.com <span>Socaial Media name</span>
    <li>Phone : 0895 788 <span>Socaial Media Username</span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

И более старый:

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 1em 0;
}

li {
  display: table-row;
}

span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <p> CONTACT US :</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Mywebsite.Com Socaial <span> Media Username</span>
    <li>Username@domain.com <span>Socaial Media name</span>
    <li>Phone : 0895 788 <span>Socaial Media Username</span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это нужно было?

```css
.contact ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.contact ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.contact ul li span:first-child {
  width: 190px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <p> CONTACT US :</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Mywebsite.Com Socaial</span>
      <span>Media Username</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Username@domain.com</span>
      <span>Socaial Media name</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Phone : 0895 788</span>
      <span>Socaial Media Username</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Так тут ширина фиксированная :(

Comment: @Qwertiy я раньше подобное верстал либо так, либо таблицей. Что вспомнил, то и сделал) Тот же `display: contents;` как-то мимо меня пролетел, я такой и не знал.

Comment: Ну у меня и без него получилось - с display: table. Впрочем, меня там немного смущает текст вместо ячеек, но Хром понял, а в других я не посмотрел. В принципе можно изменить разметку как у тебя. Кстати, вариант с фиксированной шириной можно сделать без изменения разметки - padding и отрицательный text-indent (сработает только при условии отсутствия переносов строк).